# Can I use an anonymous type in a List<T> instead of a helper class?

Tags: c#, generics, anonymous-types

I need a list with some objects for calculation.

my current code looks like this

```
private class HelperClass
{
    public DateTime TheDate {get;set;}
    public TimeSpan TheDuration {get;set;}
    public bool Enabled {get;set;}
}

private TimeSpan TheMethod()
{
    // create entries for every date
    var items = new List<HelperClass>();
    foreach(DateTime d in GetAllDatesOrdered())
    {
        items.Add(new HelperClass { TheDate = d, Enabled = GetEnabled(d), });
    }

    // calculate the duration for every entry
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
        var item = items[i];
        if (i == items.Count -1) // the last one
            item.TheDuration = DateTime.Now - item.TheDate;
        else
            item.TheDuration = items[i+1].TheDate - item.TheDate;
    }

    // calculate the total duration and return the result
    var result = TimeSpan.Zero;
    foreach(var item in items.Where(x => x.Enabled))
        result = result.Add(item.TheDuration);
    return result;
}
```

Now I find it a bit ugly just to introduce a type for my calculation (HelperClass).
My first approach was to use `Tuple<DateTime, TimeSpan, bool>` like I usually do this but since I need to modify the TimeSpan after creating the instance I can't use Tuple since `Tuple.ItemX` is readonly.

I thought about an anonymous type, but I can't figure out how to init my List

```
var item1 = new { TheDate = DateTime.Now,
                  TheDuration = TimeSpan.Zero, Enabled = true };

var items = new List<?>(); // How to declare this ???
items.Add(item1);
```

Comment: The fields of an anonymous type are [`readonly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) - they can only be set during construction - so no better than the `Tuple` idea.

Comment: btw, `result.Add` is not mutating `result` but returning you a new `TimeSpan`. Thus, the current implementation was always returning 0.

Comment: You are right, my real world code did this right. Forget to include this in the example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a projection looks like the way forward to me - but you can compute the durations as you go, by "zipping" your collection with itself, offset by one. You can then do the *whole* method in one query:

```
// Materialize the result to avoid computing possibly different sequences
var allDatesAndNow = GetDatesOrdered().Concat(new[] { DateTime.Now })
                                      .ToList();

return allDatesNow.Zip(allDatesNow.Skip(1),
                       (x, y) => new { Enabled = GetEnabled(x),
                                       Duration = y - x })
                  .Where(x => x.Enabled)
                  .Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (t, pair) => t + pair.Duration);
```

The `Zip` call pairs up each date with its subsequent one, converting each pair of values into a duration and an enabled flag. The `Where` call filters out disabled pairs. The `Aggregate` call sums the durations from the resulting pairs.

Comment: Isn't `Concat`'s argument an IEnumerable? You probably meant `new[] { DateTime.Now }` or similar.

Comment: @mikez: Whoops, yes - will fix.

Comment: +1 because you also fix a bug in the original where it always returns 0.

Comment: Didn't know about the Zip() function. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You **could** do it with LINQ like:

```
var itemsWithoutDuration = GetAllDatesOrdered()
    .Select(d => new { TheDate = d, Enabled = GetEnabled(d) })
    .ToList();
var items = itemsWithoutDuration
    .Select((it, k) => new { TheDate = it.d, Enabled = it.Enabled, 
         TheDuration = (k == (itemsWithoutDuration.Count - 1) ? DateTime.Now : itemsWithoutDuration[k+1].TheDate) - it.TheDate })
    .ToList();
```

But by that point the `Tuple` is both more readable and more concise!

Comment: But the OP needs another property, `TheDuration`, which is calculated later

Comment: @mikez: Thanks, I missed that. I added a default so that the anonymous class has a placeholder for it that can be updated later.

Comment: I'd never tried to modify them before, so I don't think I'd realized that. By the time you workaround it (as per my latest edit) it's far worse than the original `Tuple` was.

Comment: @DocMax: It doesn't have to be though - see my answer :)